# Is it possible to set a different host port than the container's exposed port in docker?

Tags: docker, port, portforwarding, kubernetes

Is it possible to set a different host port than the container's exposed port in docker? For example `docker run -name some_container -p 80:8080 -i -t some_img` If so, is it `-p host:container` or `-p container:host`? I've looked through the docs and haven't found any examples of this nor details on the publish option for `docker run`.

Additionally, I don't want to use the same port as the container because that is where Kubernete's api-server is listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is host:container and it is possible to set different port on the host.
[This Link](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#connect-using-network-port-mapping) has some good examples.

Comment: Ah thanks, I was looking at `docker run`'s referrence and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can map any host port to container port unless it is being used by other application

```
docker run -p 80:8080 --name=centos centos:latest
```

it is host:container format.